# Is it possible to debug with multiple simulators at the same time without stopping the previous tasks?

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, ios11, xcode9

In Xcode 9 there is new option to Run multiple simulators at the same time. When I tried launch second simulator its forced to stop the running instance. Is it possible to debug in multiple simulators without stopping the already running simulator's process. I want to debug with both simulators at the same time like real device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the simulator, you must choose a new device from Hardware > Devices. The new instance will starts.

Then, choose your model on Xcode.

https://help.apple.com/simulator/mac/9.0/index.html?localePath=en.lproj#/devd856f9e4c

More description available here.

**NOTE** : Till now , its not possible to debug in both simulators at the same time. You can only check UI , if you add a new simulator the instance of previous will be ended.

Comment: It's just launching new simulator. Not starts with the instance. I want to debug with both simulators at the same time like real device.

Comment: Can we run an app simultaneously on both- Device(iPhone) and Simulator?

Answer (score 4):

It's not possible to start a second simulator without stopping the already running process. However you can just re-launch your app in the first simulator, and select **Debug -> Attach to process -> Your App** in Xcode. This way both apps can run simultaneously and will stop at the same breakpoints.